# Database Schema for group

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

I have a simple user and group database.

User: uid(pk), name, password ( don't worry about password in plain)

Group: gid(pk), name, owner_uid

Member: uid (fk), gid (fk) ( a user can belong to multiple  group)

Now, I do not trust my database administrator and want to encrypt/secure specific coloumns so that db admin cannot be able to add any existing uid to any gid. How I could modify my scema and which coloumn I should encrypt.

I have a encryption key which is assumed to stay secure and I wanted to utilize sql queries also so cannot complete encrypt the tables and store as blob.

Comment: Change your database administrator

Comment: I eish I could 

Comment: You should be working on an hashing system so that only via frontend you can add a valid info to the dB.

Comment: Could you explain little more

Comment: Does your administrator access your source codes or dlls or jars? (Maybe with decompiler tools), Or only access to your database?

Comment: No, he do not have access to source code or .so

Comment: Your code is in C ? If you really want to do this look Mysql salt password and apply this to your database.

Comment: Yes, its in C. I know about salt password hash thing but how I could I stop my db admin to add a unrelated uid to gid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can not perform this requirement with database constraints. You can manage it by programming. However if you write some triggers to handle it, your (bad) administrator can access triggers too.

Add an extra column to `Member` like `key_info`.

1. In `Insert`: make a hash code (like sha256Hex) with combination of `uid` and `gid` and specific **salt**. And insert with `uid` and `gid` into `Member`.
2. In `Select`s from `Member`: you have an extra **difficulty**. You should select the records (from `Member`) that have correct hash code.

If you have a big and complex salt and your administrator can not access the salt (as you said in comments), he/she can not find the codec algorithm. So if he/she added some records into `Member`, your codes ignore the added record in selects, because the `key_info` can not be true.